# resolve libraries on click intellij?

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, pom.xml, lib

Imagine a situation like this.

I'm using maven for my project. I have used a 3rd party lib for my project (say **libA**). And in my local m2, I have 2 versions of it (say ***v1*** and ***v2***).

I have used **v1** of that lib for my project. So I have specified the version as **v1** in **pom.xml** too. But when I do <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>mouse-click</kbd>, on a method of that lib which is used inside one of my classes in my code, intellij always opens the **.class** file for that method which belongs to **v2 not v1**.

What has gone wrong here. Or is it a known bug??

Comment: have you tried reimport all maven projects?

Comment: There might be a possibility that some other library using v2 so your application resolve dependency using v2. Can you please remove the v2 version from you m2 then verify it works fine or it download it again? You can also check dependency hierarchy.

Comment: @ShubhenduPramanik yes.

Comment: @HemantSingh as I searched no other in this project using v2.

Comment: How both library declarations look like?

Comment: @Andrey wht do you mean by declaration?

Comment: The <dependency> section for these libraries in pom.xml file.

Comment: @Andrey it is not a publicly available jar. What I have done is, I have specified the group-id and artifact-id. And I have added the version in root pom. (not the service it self)

Comment: Does it helps if you declare the dependency and specify the version in the module directory?

Comment: Try also 2018.2 from https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/nextversion